# Duvida sobre como iterar sobre um ArrayList

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, arraylist

Tenho esse exercicio abaixo para fazer porem na questão "D" estou com dificuldades , se alguem puder me explicar como devo fazer :

> 2. a) Crie uma interface chamada `ModeloContato` com os métodos `getNome()`, `getTelefone()` e `getEndereco()`, todos sem parâmetros e
>      retornando `String`, `int` e `String` respectivamente;
>
>    b) Crie uma classe concreta chamada `Contato` que implemente os
>      métodos abstratos da interface criada na letra a. `Contato` deve
>      incluir métodos `set` e os atributos `nome`, `telefone` e `endereço`.
>
> c) Crie um `ArrayList` do tipo `Contato`, representando uma agenda.
>   Adicione contatos atribuindo valores iniciais aos atributos.
>
> **d) Imprima os dados dos contatos cadastrados na letra C.**
>
> e) Implemente a busca de um contato na agenda, imprimindo quando o
>   resultado for encontrado ou informando que não foi encontrado se for o
>   caso.

Segue o código já feito :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayList<Contato> agenda = new ArrayList<Contato>();

Contato a = new Contato ();
Contato b = new Contato ();
Contato c = new Contato ();


for (int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++){
    Contato contato1 = new Contato();
    agenda.add(contato1);
    agenda.get(i).setNome("joao");
    agenda.add(contato1);
    agenda.get(i).setEndereco("Rua Joao Camara");
    agenda.add(contato1);
    agenda.get(i).setTelefone(3589);

}

for(int i = 1; i <= 1; i++){
    System.out.println(agenda.get(0).getNome());
    System.out.println(agenda.get(0).getEndereco());
    System.out.println(agenda.get(0).getTelefone());    
}

}
```

Se puderem me dá apenas um exemplo de como fazer seria ótimo, se me derem a resposta eu não vou aprender como fazer.

Answer (score 3):

Se seu `ArrayList` é do tipo `Contato`, você pode utilizar este *for*:

```
for(ObjType t: yourArrayList) {
  //aqui você exibe os gets
  // a partir da variavel t
}
```

Desta forma você abstrai o indice, já que o objetivo é exibir apenas os dados de cada objeto armazenado.

Claro que nada te impede de fazer com a sintaxe do for tradicional também:

```
for(int i = 0; i < yourArrayList.size(); i++) {
    // aqui você invoca cada objeto e suas 
    // propriedades utilizando o yourArrayList.get(i)
}
```

Mas tendo em vista a letra E, sugiro que abstraia a exibição, criando um método que receba um objeto do tipo Contato e exiba seus dados:

```
public static void exibirContato(Contato c) {
    System.out.println(c.getNome());
    System.out.println(c.getEndereco());
    System.out.println(c.getTelefone()); 
}
```

E no laço, basta passar o `seuArrayList.get(i)` ou se utilizar o primeiro exemplo, simplesmente passar o `t` para este método. Dessa forma, quando implementar a busca e o contato for encontrado, você pode simplesmente chamar esse método para exibir, ao invés de ficar repetindo toda a chamada de getters novamente.

Answer (score 1):

O item D quer que você simplesmente itere sobre a lista. Você pode iterar de diversas maneiras diferentes em [java](/questions/tagged/java), mas a minha favorita é a seguinte:

```
ArrayList<Contato> agenda;

// preenche agenda

for (Contato contato: agenda) {
    // faz ação no item "contato"
}
```

De qualquer sorte, o item C não está devidamente respondido. Se você for verificar, após o povoamento, você terá 9 elementos, repetidos de 3 em 3. Você só precisa adicionar o item uma única vez na lista.

---

No Java 8, podemos usar o `forEach` da lista. Usando da [resposta do  @ArticunoL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/230619/64969) o método `exibirContato`, seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
ArrayList<Contato> agenda;

// preenche agenda

agenda.forEach(RespArticuno::exibirContato);
```

Comment: Me explique um pouco mais sobre o Item C amigo , eu não consegui assimilar com responder . eu devo retirar o primeiro for ?

Comment: @FelipeLamarao como esta dúvida é sobre a letra C, seria mais interessante fazer isso em outra pergunta, para não desvirtuar o objetivo desta. Mas sugiro também abstrair em um método a parte, do que fazer estrutural, já que imagino que seja um exercicio para aprendizado sobre POO.

Comment: Obrigado, Irei fazer